# How to setup an anchor in Stellar network using Windows?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, postgres

While there is a great deal of documentation on installing the packages, however, I couldn't follow it properly to install the stellar-core, horizon and Postgres database in windows. There is not sufficient information for new players. Any idea of how to set up these three components in windows? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using docker. 
Ubuntu 18 is probably the best is to run stellar on. Controversial? Probably. I bet you could even run stellar on a virtual machine through windows. What is the specific issue? Alot of times windows has dependency issues with having to manually install packages.